# Rails 4 - can't connect to the table on the database on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following a tutorial to learn how to use nested attributes ,I am making a survey , but something is wrong as i cant insert any data in the question table

that's what I did :

Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :survey
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

---

Survey model

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }
end
```

---

views/survey/_form.erb

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>


 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>



  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |ff| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= ff.label :content , "question"%><br>
  <%= ff.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <% end %> 

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

---

SurveysController

```
# GET /surveys/new
  def new
@survey = Survey.new
3.times { @survey.questions.new }
end
```

---

Now when i click submit only the survey name is saved , but no Questions !!
like this :

```
2.1.1 :023 > Question.all
Question Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

---

the create action

```
# POST /surveys
# POST /surveys.json
def create
@survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @survey.save
    format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @survey }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

---

```
 private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_survey
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name)
end
end
```

---

I added another model [answer]

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

changed Question model to this

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :survey
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and i changed the survey to

```
# GET /surveys/new
def new
@survey = Survey.new
1.times do
question = @ survey.questions.build
2.times { question.answers.build }
end
end
```

now the same previous problem with answers
how should i handle strong parameters

should it be like this

```
def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, answers_attributes: [:content]) 
end
```

Comment: Can you post the "create" action? And if you use strong parameters, also the definition of "def survey_params"

Comment: Did you try without 3.times?

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis i add the create action

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy same problem , thanks in advanced :)

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis you was right , the " def survey_params " was missing ... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have the `questions_attributes` listed in the allowed parameters of your Survey.

Make sure your `survey_params` includes questions attributes like so:

```
private

def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes: [:content]) 
end
```

If you have other survey attributes or question attributes you need to allow them here also.

[Strong parameters with nested attributes documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters)

Comment: i added another model called answer and i have the same problem

how should i handle it ?

i put the code in the question

Comment: it worked :)
i changed it to this

def survey_params
          params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes:[:content, :id, :survey_id, 
                                                 answers_attributes:[:content, :id, :questions_id]
                                                 ])
        end